# MVC 5 model validation regex to block special characters

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to block special characters except ( space, _ , - , @ , . ) with the regular expression below using MVC, but it's not working:

```
[RegularExpression("[-_,A-Za-z0-9]$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Strings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "NoQuote")]
public string custCode { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regex provided to the `RegularExpressionAttribute` validation attribute specifies that the value is valid if and only if the expression matches. The expression you have provided though will match anytime the *last character* is valid, regardless of the rest.

Therefore you need to anchor it on both sides to make sure the entire value is checked start-to-finish, then make sure your string only consists of zero *or more* (one or more?) of these valid characters using a duplication operator such as `*` - adjust this as necessary for your requirements. For example:

```
"^[-_,A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

Also, you mentioned you wanted to include space, `.`, and `@` so you should add these to the character class too:

```
"^[-_, @.A-Za-z0-9]*$"
```